# Google stop indexing my IP and index

Tags: indexing

I have a domain that is pointing to my servers IP using a A-record. Only problem is, Google is indexing my site both by domainname AND IP-Adress, and that doesn't look very good in the search results.. How can i solve that?

Comment: Use Google webmaster tools. Anyway I think this should be in http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sorry about that, will keep that in mind in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what technologies you're using on the web site, you may be able to make the robots.txt file smart enough to allow crawling for the domain name and disallow it for the IP address.

Another alternative is to set up your web server with "virtual hosts" or "host headers" that will prevent the site from even responding to requests to the IP address.

Comment: My server is running Apache with PHP so i guess i could do something in PHP to detect the requested URL. But how do i detect if the "user" (read googlebot) accessed the page through IP or Domain name?

Comment: Anton, www.linuxplanet.com/linuxplanet/tutorials/6660/2

Comment: and http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php  using the above approach combined with a script checking what the user actually requested will get you where you want to go.  Google's robots make requests to your site almost just like any other user.  You should be able to test by hitting your hostname/robots.txt vs ip/robots.txt externally and depending on what you hit you'll get a different result (one that allows robots and one that does not)

Comment: Thank you! Solved it using the PHP $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] variable =)